# .then is undefined when I try to save in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I'm new to node.js.
I got this message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Here is the code:

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const userRegister = new UserRegister({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    nickname: req.body.nickname,
    email: req.body.password,
    password: req.body.password,
    level: 0
  });
  console.log(req.body.nickname + " " + req.body.email + " " + req.body.password);
  userRegister
    .save()
    .then(doc => {
      console.log(doc);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "User created"
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err)
        console.log("error => " + err)
      res.status(409).json({
        message: "ERROR"
      })
    });
});
```

and the Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userRegister = mongoose.Schema({
  _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  nickname: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  level: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("UserRegister", userRegister);
```

I don't really understand why it says ".then undefined".
(the body is good)

Comment: Where is `UserRegister` defined?

Comment: Hello !
I updated the post you can see it now

Comment: better indenting would make that easier to read

Comment: Hello, it is in the code !

Comment: To clarify, ".then" is not undefined. It's telling you that the object you are trying to call ".then" on is undefined, which is a valuable piece of information. ".then" is to be used after a Promise resolves, so try wrapping the declaration of UserRegister in a promise.

Comment: What version of mongoose is in your `package.json`? According to [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) calling `save()` without a callback should return a `Promise` as you expect. You might be using an older version without realizing?

Comment: I'm using "mongoose": "^5.3.14",

Answer (score 1):

It seems like function "save" does not return Promise. But in source code it does...
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L385

Also you can try "create" method.
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L2646

Maybe it will be hellpfull:

```
   const result = new SomeModel({...});

   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Save model
      result.save(err => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(new Error(`Error with exam ersult save... ${err}`));
        }
        // Return saved model
        return resolve(result);
      })
      .then(res => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
```

Comment: that's what I also understand. I don't know why it wouldn't return a promise. It's started to be complicated for me, I'm new in nodejs and this was clean in my head with the .save(). As I said, in the video he uses like I use myself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

check if the model is the promising type or not if this is not the promising then use callback

[mongoose promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#built-in-promises)

> assert.ok(user instanceof Promise); // this return ture or false

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
      const userRegister = new UserRegister({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        nickname: req.body.nickname,
        email: req.body.password,
        password: req.body.password,
        level: 0
      });

      console.log(req.body.nickname + " " + req.body.email + " " + req.body.password);


      var user = userRegister.save()

     assert.ok(user instanceof Promise); 

     // if assert.ok return true then use user.then 
    // else use callback  userRegister.save( function(doc){ })    

      user.then(doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "User created"
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err)
          console.log("error => " + err)
        res.status(409).json({
          message: "ERROR"
        })
      });
    });
```

Comment: In the tuto I'm following, he doesn't use assert or any kind of things like this. It just does like i've written and it works. you can see it at 15m57 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDrU305J1yw&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q&index=6

Comment: I don't know what it is the goal of assert. Im looking at it

Answer (score -1):

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const userRegister = await UserRegister.create({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            nickname: req.body.nickname,
            email: req.body.password,
            password: req.body.password,
            level: 0
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("error => " + err)
        res.status(409).json({
        message: "ERROR"
        })
    }

    console.log(userRegister);
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "User created"
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thx for the answer. It should probably work but i wanted the version with .then to answer how it works. I already know await !

Comment: @dun32 no they didn't. It doesn't go before `router.post()`.